# show Gameobject one time only unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have Game object I want to display it only one time if I have score < 2000 game object shown and if score > 2000 game object not shown , after that when score <2000 again game object not shown again (I assign game object as my image into inspector )

```
if (Scores < 2000) {

    Rock1.gameObject.SetActive (true);

}
if (Scores > 2000) {

    Rock1.gameObject.SetActive (false);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use a boolean variable. You can use this code:

```
bool hideOneTime = false;

...

if (!hideOneTime)
{
    if (score < 2000)
    {
        Rock1.gameObject.SetActive (true);
    }
    else if (score > 2000)
    {
        Rock1.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        hideOneTime = true;            
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 4):

You want a GameObject to display when score is < 2000 then hide the GameObject when 2000 is > 2000 but don't do it again.

You can do this with a boolan variable as a flag in the `Update` function but since you want this to run once, it is better to do it in a coroutine function. Unity's `Start` coroutine functon is fine and will start itself. This will run once and will not check it again since the coroutine function will exit right away unlike the `Update` function.

```
public int scores;
public GameObject Rock1;

IEnumerator Start()
{
    //Wait until score is < 2000
    while (!(scores < 2000))
        yield return null;

    //Show Object
    Rock1.SetActive(true);

    //Wait again until score is > 2000
    while (!(scores > 2000))
        yield return null;

    //Hide Object
    Rock1.SetActive(false);

    //Done. Coroutine stops!
}
```

Comment: Really clever use of a coroutine, using it to hold state instead of a `boolean`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply test the status of the Game Object.

For example if you want to show it and execute the SetActive once you can do :

```
if(!Rock1.gameObject.activeSelf)
    Rock1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

And vice versa, if you want to hide it.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Write the code inside the Start() function rather than Update() function.
Or the game object will be spawned infinitely before it crashes.

If you want to hide the gameobject, then try turning off the renderer through code, but if you want ur object to go forever with its logic try to destroy it when you want and use IEnumerator if you want to have any control over time. Thank you.